# Connection refused when connecting to MySql using NodeJS mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, mariadb, plesk

I am running a NodeJS app hosted on a (linux) dedicated Plesk server, under a subdomain.
Trying to connect to a MariaDB mysql server.
The NodeJS code:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "myDatabase"
});
global.MYSQL_CONNECTION = con;

function Connect(onSuccess){
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("MySQL connected successfully.");
        onSuccess(con);
      });
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```js
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

However, when I run `mysql -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword` on my bash terminal it connects fine, meaning the credentials are correct and the user has permissions.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the solution to this.
All I had to do was to change the host to 127.0.0.1 :

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  database: "myDatabase"
});
```

I am unsure of the reason. It most probably has something to do with the fact that this runs on a subdomain. Would be great if anyone could specify the reason.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the IP address for `localhost`, `localhost` isn't a domain nor IP address and therefore certain packages (such as `mysql`) don't actually support the term.

Comment: @Tyler2P well that would be the case, if I didn't already use localhost as the host for another website.

Comment: It used to work but stopped working with newer mysql.  This is correct solution.